# Java - Resizing font to fit area

Tags: java, fonts, font-size

Many times over the years, I have been faced with the problem of resizing text in to fit in a certain area on a Java GUI. My solution was usually to work around the issue by:

- Redesigning the interface to avoid the problem
- Changing the area to fit the size of the text
- Doing a binary search for the correct size font to fit the string(when I could not do either of the first 2)

While working on another project recently that needed to determine the correct font size for a given region quickly, my binary search method was too slow(I suspect because of the dynamic memory allocations involved with creating and measuring a font many times in sequence) and introduced noticeable lag into my application. What I needed was a faster easier way to calculate a font size that would allow a given string to be rendered to fit within a defined region of the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it occurred to me that there was a much easier and faster way that only required a few allocations at run time. This new method eliminated the need for any kind of search and requires only 1 measurement to be taken, it does, however, need to make one assumption, one that is perfectly reasonable for most applications.

- The width and height of the font must be the proportional to the point size of the font. This happens on all but the most obscure transformations done to a rendering context.

Using this assumption, we can compute the ratio of the font's dimensions to the point size, and linearly extrapolate to find the font size that we need for the given region. Some code that I wrote to do this is below:

**Edit:**
The accuracy of the initial measurement is limited by the size of the base font. Using a really small font size as the base can throw off the results. But the larger the size of the base font the more accurate the more accurate the linear approximation is.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class FontUtilities
{   
    public static Font createFontToFit
    (
        String value,
        double width,
        double height,
        Font base,
        Graphics context
    )
    {
        double measuredWidth;
        double measuredHeight;
        double baseFontSize;
        FontMetrics ruler;
        Rectangle2D bounds;
        double heightBasedFontSize;
        double widthBasedFontSize;
        GlyphVector vector;
        Shape outline;

        if
        (
            (value == null) ||
            (base == null) ||
            (context == null) ||
            (width != width) ||
            (height != height)
        )
        {
            return null;
        }

        //measure the size of the string in the current font size
        baseFontSize = base.getSize2D();
        ruler = context.getFontMetrics(base);


        vector = base.createGlyphVector(ruler.getFontRenderContext(), value);

        //use the bounds measurement on the outline of the text since this is the only
        //measurement method that seems to be bug free and consistent in java
        outline = vector.getOutline(0, 0);
        bounds = outline.getBounds();

        measuredWidth = bounds.getWidth();
        measuredHeight = bounds.getHeight();

        //assume that each of the width and the height of the string
        //is proportional to the font size, calculate the ratio
        //and extrapolate linearly to determine the needed font size.
        //should have 2 font sizes one for matching the width, and one for
        //matching the height, return the least of the 2
        widthBasedFontSize = (baseFontSize*width)/measuredWidth;
        heightBasedFontSize = (baseFontSize*height)/measuredHeight;

        if(widthBasedFontSize < heightBasedFontSize)
        {
            return base.deriveFont(base.getStyle(), (float)widthBasedFontSize);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.deriveFont(base.getStyle(), (float)heightBasedFontSize);
        }
    }
}
```